# flutter firebase check if collection is empty

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I' am using Firestore on my Flutter application, I'm fetching data inside a ListView. I wanna know how to check if a collection has no documents on Firestore?

Edit:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: db.collection('favorite_encheres').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (QuerySnapshot.size == 0) {
                return Container(
                .
                .
                .
                )
                else
                return ListView
                 (
                 .
                 .
                 )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no separate operation to check whether a collections exists. Collections automatically come into existence when there's a document in them, and disappear when the last document is deleted.

If you're already loading the data into a `StreamBuilder` you can check whether the [`QuerySnapshot.size`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/size.html) is greater than 0.

If you don't need to load all the data, but just want to know if any documents exist in the collection, you can use a query with [`limit`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/limit.html) of 1. If you get no results, you know the collection is empty.

Comment: i got an error using QuerySnapshot.size, "Instance member 'size' can't be accessed using static" i just edited the post and added my code, do you mind checking it

Comment: The `size` property exists on a specific instance of the `QuerySnapshot` class, so in your code that'd be `snapshot.size`.

Comment: I replaced it and now i'm getting this error "The getter 'size' isn't defined for the type 'AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>'. Try importing the library that defines 'size' "

Comment: Arg.... I missed that your `snapshot` is an `AsyncSnapshot`, while `size` is defined on `QuerySnapshot` (as said). I *highly* recommend learning to navigate these types yourself, but in your code it'd be: `if (snapshot.hashData && snapshot.data.size == 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check If Collection is exits or not like this

```
 Future<bool> _isCollectionExits() async {
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> _query =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collectionPath').get();

    if (_query.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      // Collection exits
      return true;
    } else {
      // Collection not exits
      return false;
    }
  }
```

You can use like this

```
bool _isCollExits = await _isCollectionExits();
```

Comment: isn't this bad approach since you querying the full collection?

Comment: Currently I am not aware about any other way, It's gonna be great If we find another workaround rather than this

Comment: is there any other way?